# Getting pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: mismatched input '(' expecting {<EOF>

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to rank the  column 'Product' based on the revenue from below data frame- salesDF

```
salesDF=
+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
|transactionID|Product| category|produtType|Revenue|
+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------+
|          105| Lenova|   laptop|      high|  40000|
|          111| Lenova|   tablet|    medium|  20000|
|          103|   dell|   laptop|     medum|  25000|
|          107| iphone|cellPhone|     small|  70000|
|          113| lenovo|cellPhone|    medium|   8000|
|          108|     mi|cellPhone|     medum|  10000|
```

Now below iam using spark sql to rank each Product based on the Revenue

```
rankTheRevenue= salesDF.createTempView("Ranking_DF")
rankProduct= session.sql("select Product, Revenue, rank() over(partion by Product order by Revenue) as Rank_revenue from Ranking_DF")
rankProduct.show()
```

### But iam getting following error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
mismatched input '(' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'EXCEPT', 'FROM', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INTERSECT', 'LATERAL', 'LIMIT', 'ORDER', 'MINUS', 'SORT', 'UNION', 'WHERE', 'WINDOW', '-'}(line 1, pos 36)
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me to resolve this kind of issue

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **typo** at **`partition by`** clause as `partion by`.

Try with:

```
rankTheRevenue= salesDF.createTempView("Ranking_DF")
rankProduct= session.sql("select Product, Revenue, rank() over(partition by Product order by Revenue) as Rank_revenue from Ranking_DF")
rankProduct.show()
```